# "Kич" или "китч"?

Tags: словарь

В статье [Китч](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%E8%F2%F7) на википедии, например, это слово употребляется то как "китч", то как "кич".

Какое написание правильное (или предпочтительное)?

Comment: добавить контекст и значение слова, например.

Comment: Например "Как правильно: кич или китч?"

Comment: А лучше пойти на сайт http://gramota.ru/ и вбить слово в форму "проверка слова".

Comment: В статье[1] об этом слове например это слово написано то так,то так. [link](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%E8%F2%F7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Согласно, например, Словарю иностранных слов Комлева Н.Г 2006 года, допустимы оба варианта.
Поискать по словарям можно тут: http://dic.academic.ru/

Comment: Да это понятно, что оба допустимы. Вопрос стоял, какой **предпочтительнее**.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите, чтобы вас понял любой носитель русского языка, то лучше писать "псевдоискусство" или "ширпотреб" (*товары широкого потребления*). Слово "кич" (я как носитель русского языка написал бы так, потому что сочетание "тч" в русском непроизносимо и есть влияние русского корня -кич-, *ср. кичливый, кичиться*) в России малоупотребительно, но людям, увлекающиеся английским языком или искусством о нём известно.

Посмотрел этимологию, первоначально слово появилось из немецкого языка, где никакого "т" нет.

Comment: Псевдоискусство - то, что выдаётся за искусство, им не являясь. Китч же может быть и откровенным (кроме того, является ли он искусством или нет, вопрос спорный).  Что касается написания, то заимствованные слова на -тч так и пишутся: скотч, матч.

Comment: @user31264 Во-первых; вы сами себе противоречите, когда сперва заявляете, что кич нельзя назвать псевдоискусством, а потом сами отмечаете спорность того положения, что кич можно назвать искусством. Если принадлежность к искусству нуждается в доказаельствах - то это псевдоискуство. Во-вторых; касательно написания, в современном русском поменялась традиция адаптации английских слов, и сейчас чаще их записывают как слышится, а не как пишется. Частотность слова "кич" в 10 раз превышает частотность "китча"

Comment: Нет, утверждение "eсли принадлежность к искусству нуждается в доказаельствах - то это псевдоискуство" неверно, вы или не поняли, или намерено искажаете то, что я написал.  А откуда у вас данные по частотности, интересно?

Answer (score 1):

Спорный вопрос. В таких случаях, когда нет прямых оснований предпочесть один вариант другому, норма написания заимствованных слов обычно определяется по факту, а традиция пока не сложилась. Мне нравится вариант "китч" чисто зрительно, он передаёт ощущение заимствования, чего-то иностранного. Но это, конечно, субъективно.

Ну, подождем - увидим.

Answer (score 1):

1. С одной стороны, `китч`, по аналогии со словами `матч`, `скотч`, `патч`.
2. С другой стороны, все перечисленные слова заимствованны из английского, `китч` же - из немецкого.  В немецком языке tsch - отдельный тетраграф: `Kitsch` без t (`Kisch`) читалось бы как "киш".  В английском не так: и tch, и ch читаются как "ч".
3. С третьей стороны, англичане, тоже заимствовавшие `Kitsch`, не стали менять его написание (за исключением того, что пишут его со строчной буквы).
4. По частотности в Корпусе примерное равенство, если смотреть по количеству документов.

Резюме: пока не найдены другие слова, заимствованные из немецкого с тетраграфом tsch, нет и решающих доводов в ту или иную пользу. **Лично мне** больше нравится вариант с `т`.  Скорее всего, оба варианта правильные.